# Mongodb monitoring via Elasticsearch agent

Tags: json, mongodb, docker, elasticsearch, etl

I'm running an Elasticsearch agent for monitoring mongodb's metrics and logs using the official [agent](https://docs.elastic.co/en/integrations/mongodb). My database is running in a container and the logs are getting stored in the container's stdout file.

Container's log file is located at the following location `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container_id>/<container_name>.log`. The same path I've passed in the elasticsearch agent's configuration.

Database docker container's log entry looks like the following:

```
{
    "log": "{\"t\":{\"$date\":\"2024-01-04T11:19:50.685+00:00\"},\"s\":\"I\",  \"c\":\"NETWORK\",  \"id\":22944,   \"ctx\":\"conn35365\",\"msg\":\"Connection ended\",\"attr\":{\"remote\":\"SOME_IP_ADDRESS:SOME_PORT\",\"uuid\":\"5a9f7c37-deed-4235-97a3-ce9bfddc277e\",\"connectionId\":35365,\"connectionCount\":60}}\n",
    "stream": "stdout",
    "time": "2024-01-04T11:19:50.68593377Z"
}
```

Logs generating directly by mongodb, it looks something like this:

```
{
    "t": {
        "$date": "2024-01-04T11:19:50.685+00:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "NETWORK",
    "id": 22944,
    "ctx": "conn35365",
    "msg": "Connection ended",
    "attr": {
        "remote": "SOME_IP_ADDRESS:SOME_PORT",
        "uuid": "5a9f7c37-deed-4235-97a3-ce9bfddc277e",
        "connectionId": 35365,
        "connectionCount": 60
    }
}
```

The issue is that, the data in container's log entry is inside the `log` field and is also having escape characters. This is not the acceptable format for elasticsearch's mongodb [agent](https://docs.elastic.co/en/integrations/mongodb), as it accepts the database logs to come at the root level and not inside the log field.

Elasticsearch is dropping all such log entries, because of missing fields. I'm vaguely aware that writing custom processor can fix this, but not sure.

How can I fix this ?